# css grid 100% width and max-width

Tags: css, grid

I have created a grid and now have problems with max-width. I want to have containers which take up the available width and are restricted by a left and right margin. This containers can contain children. These children may be bigger then the parent container and may be moved with the class .move-to-right-border to the right border to take up full width on the right.

I now have added a max-width to the container, to restrict the width. But now i have the problem that i can't set child elements to take up full width. I tried with 100vw, but width 100vw the scrollbar is included. Has anybody a solution for this problem?

Maybe it gets more clear with this example, comment max-width in and out to see what i want.

```
.row-right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  max-width: 700px; /* to see the problem comment max-width in and out */
  width: calc(100% - 100px - 200px);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.move-to-right-border {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% + 100px);
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJymOL

Comment: You just wana keep even margins on the sides? Have you tried adding padding to your body? body{ padding-right:200px;} seemed to work well for me via your pen.

Comment: I have build a grid where rows can have different margins, this is the reason why the margin is added to row-right. There may be another row which behaves different.

Answer (score 1):

just use below css

CSS

```
.row-right p {
  text-align: justify;
  width : 100%
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think u r after something like this:

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #99ff99;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: #ff9999;
}

.child{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #9999ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  This is parent
  <div class="container">
    This is container
    <div class="child">
        This is child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```